# Browser second page not openinig in Android ICS

Tags: android, browser

In a custom device with HSPA modem ( USB interface) I am not able to browse multiple pages in Android ICS 4.0.3, kernel 3.0.8

I am able to get PPP interface in netcfg with IP
If I launch the ping www.google.com from terminal I am able to get continuous resoponse
but if I launch the browser the ping is giving the error

ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available

and browser also not loading more than one page. For the second page it is keep on loading, after some time it reports a network has occurred

In ppp_async.c OBUFFSIZE is 4096 I tried with 10240 also but it didn't worked

and I tried echo 83886080 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max then also same issue.

The tcp buffer sizes in init.rc are

```
setprop net.tcp.buffersize.default 4096,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208
setprop net.tcp.buffersize.wifi    524288,1048576,2097152,262144,524288,1048576
setprop net.tcp.buffersize.lte     524288,1048576,2097152,262144,524288,1048576
setprop net.tcp.buffersize.umts    4094,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208
setprop net.tcp.buffersize.hspa    4094,87380,262144,4096,16384,262144
setprop net.tcp.buffersize.edge    4093,26280,35040,4096,16384,35040
setprop net.tcp.buffersize.gprs    4092,8760,11680,4096,8760,11680
```

Did anybody faced this problem any suggestions to debug this